# How to substitude/add root element in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Assume I have following HTML code:

```
<p>Hello, bla-bla-bla</p>
<a href="somesite">Click here</a>
```

As you can see, it doesn't have html/body tags.
What I want to do is to add html and body tags on top of the document.

I tried to add html tag with following code:

```
 var el = doc.CreateElement("html");
 var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
 doc.DocumentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
 el.AppendChildren(nodes);    
 doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(el);
```

But after that, a call `doc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo()` returns `<html></html>`.
If I change the execution order of last lines:

```
var el = doc.CreateElement("html");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
doc.DocumentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(el); 
el.AppendChildren(nodes);
```

I got `System.StackOverflowException` after the `doc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo()`.

Possible solution can be something like this:

```
doc.LoadHtml("<html>" + doc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo() + "</html>")
```

but it'll be ineffective due to full document reparsing.

Do you have any ideas, how this problem can be solved in performance-effective way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got it to work. First sample wasn't working because `doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes` returns not the copy of `HtmlNodeCollection`, but the node collection itself. It caused that all nodes from collection were deleted before adding them to `el`. The code below does the trick:

```
var el = doc.CreateElement("html");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
el.AppendChildren(nodes);    
doc.DocumentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(el);
```